# Can I specify which key I want in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

If I have an array called `$animalarray` with keys `dog`, `cat`, `bird`, can I specify which key I want to use in a foreach loop?

I'm doing something like this right now but it just returns all the values from the array

```
foreach($animalarray as $species=>$bird)
{   
    echo $bird;
}
```

I'd like this to only echo out the value under the key Bird, but this returns all values under all the keys.

Comment: Please, specify your input data and you want to see in output.

Comment: Are you planning on doing this for `dog`, `cat` and `bird`? If so you might just use `switch()` in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do `echo $animalarray['bird'];`?

You could also do this, but it's unnecessary:

```
foreach($animalarray as $species=>$bird) {   
    if ($species == 'bird') {
        echo $bird;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$allowedKeys = array('dog');

foreach($animalarray as $species=>$bird)
{   
    if(array_key_exists($species, $allowedKeys)) {
        echo $bird;
    }
}
```

It will output matches only for dogs.

Answer (score 0):

- If animal array is from database, then select it with aditional condition.
- Or you can use simple IF statement http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php